# Rendering templates preformances

Tags: wpf, performance, datatemplate

I created a propertyGrid like. 
I used an Item control which uses a viewmodel object.
The VM object has the property to be display and its relevant DataTemplates.
Everything wosrk fine. My Property grid actually act like the VS property grid

My problem is that every time the use changes the selected object (which lead to changes in the property grid) its took to much time (depends on the amount of the selected object properties). I figured out that the reason for the bad performances is the templates loading and rendering. 
so I thought that I may solve this issues by creating real controls for each object, and not just uses templates. (Create buttons and text box for each property) this will solve the loading time, I hope..

1- is there any way to creates real controls (in code) using data templates?
2- is there any other way to improve the performances of my Property grid?

The main code for the propGrid is attached to this post

Thanks, Leon

CODE:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="gridItemsControl" >    
        <Grid  Visibility="{Binding Visibility}">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="60"   MaxWidth="350" Width="{Binding Source={StaticResource firstCulWidth},Path=Width,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Converter={StaticResource widthToGridLenConverter}}"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="#ff333333" BorderThickness="0.5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            Visibility ="{Binding IsCategoryItem,Converter={StaticResource isCategoryItemToVisibilityConverter},ConverterParameter=Category}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="#FFA9BFD4" Height="25">
                    <Expander Template="{StaticResource SimpleExpanderTemp}"  ExpandDirection="Left"  IsExpanded="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="3,0,5,0"/>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Path=CategoryName,Converter={StaticResource propertyNameToDiplayNameConverter}}" FontSize="12" Foreground="White"  VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
            <Border Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="#ff333333" BorderThickness="0.5" 
                                Visibility ="{Binding IsCategoryItem,Converter={StaticResource isCategoryItemToVisibilityConverter}}">
                <Label Margin="5,0,0,0"  Content="{Binding Path=DisplayName,Converter={StaticResource propertyNameToDiplayNameConverter}}"/>
            </Border>
            <GridSplitter  Grid.Row="0"  Grid.Column="0"  Visibility ="{Binding IsCategoryItem,Converter={StaticResource isCategoryItemToVisibilityConverter}}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="4" Background="Transparent"/>
            <Border  Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="#ff333333" BorderThickness="0.5" 
                                Visibility ="{Binding IsCategoryItem,Converter={StaticResource isCategoryItemToVisibilityConverter}}">
                <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,1,10,1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                        ContentTemplate="{Binding  Path=InlineTemplate}" />
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Update: Here is the container

```
 <ItemsControl Name="propsDataGrid"   ItemsSource="{Binding Properties}" ItemTemplate ="{StaticResource gridItemsControl}">
                        <ItemsControl.ContextMenu>
                            <ContextMenu>
                                <MenuItem Header="Close all expanders" Click="MenuItem_Click" Visibility="{Binding IsAlphaBeticSort,Converter={StaticResource boolToVisConverter},ConverterParameter=VisForFalse}"></MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem Header="Expand all" Name="mnExpandeAll"  Click="mnExpandeAll_Click"  Visibility="{Binding IsAlphaBeticSort,Converter={StaticResource boolToVisConverter},ConverterParameter=VisForFalse}"></MenuItem>
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </ItemsControl.ContextMenu>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <!--<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate >
                                <Grid  Visibility="{Binding Visibility}">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="60"   MaxWidth="350" Width="{Binding Source={StaticResource firstCulWidth},Path=Width,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Converter={StaticResource widthToGridLenConverter}}"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Border Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="#ff333333" BorderThickness="0.5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                        Visibility ="{Binding IsCategoryItem,Converter={StaticResource isCategoryItemToVisibilityConverter},ConverterParameter=Category}">
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="#FFA9BFD4" Height="25">
                                            <Expander Template="{StaticResource SimpleExpanderTemp}"  ExpandDirection="Left"  IsExpanded="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="3,0,5,0"/>
                                            <Label Content="{Binding Path=CategoryName,Converter={StaticResource propertyNameToDiplayNameConverter}}" FontSize="12" Foreground="White"  VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Border>
                                <Border Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="#ff333333" BorderThickness="0.5" 
                                          Visibility ="{Binding IsCategoryItem,Converter={StaticResource isCategoryItemToVisibilityConverter}}">
                                    <Label Margin="5,0,0,0"  Content="{Binding Path=DisplayName,Converter={StaticResource propertyNameToDiplayNameConverter}}"/>
                                </Border>
                                <GridSplitter  Grid.Row="0"  Grid.Column="0"  Visibility ="{Binding IsCategoryItem,Converter={StaticResource isCategoryItemToVisibilityConverter}}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="4" Background="Transparent"/>
                                <Border  Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="#ff333333" BorderThickness="0.5" 
                                          Visibility ="{Binding IsCategoryItem,Converter={StaticResource isCategoryItemToVisibilityConverter}}">
                                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,1,10,1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                                  ContentTemplate="{Binding  Path=InlineTemplate}" />
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>-->
                </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: How is the control containing/generating the items defined?

Answer (score 0):

`DataTemplates` create "real controls" there is no gain in doing something manually which is done automatically using templates, the only thing you should worry about is **virtualization** (so that the controls for properties not in view are not created) and how your templates are wired up so that their creation is not triggered needlessly.

*(By the way, the way you create the grid, setting its width, looks like it might be redundant, you probably can just [share the size](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.issharedsizescope.aspx).)*

To make an `ItemsControl` virtualize the items you need to:

1. Set the `ItemsPanel` to a [`VirtualizingStackPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.aspx)
2. Have a control template which contains a `ScrollViewer` around the `ItemsPresenter` where the `VirtualizingStackPanel` will be.
3. Set `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll` to `true` to enable scrolling by item which allows for virtualization.

e.g.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
              ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
    <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Border Name="Bd" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                    Padding="1">
                <ScrollViewer Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Focusable="false">
                    <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <!-- ... -->
</ItemsControl>
```

If this is still too slow you could make the whole `ItemsControl` part of a template which applies *per type* as presumably the contents of this grid are dependent on the type of the item, thus a different grid should only be created if the item-type changes, also you might be able to cache the resulting templates as well (i never tried doing that though).

Comment: Thanks H.B for you replay, The reson I want to do it is to avoid the creation of those control (created by the tempaltes) more then ones. each time the user selected to view some object's property, my property grid loads/uses the Datatemplates, so I tought to improve that by crating the UIElemetns for each of my data object onces.

Comment: @leonnoah: You are probably binding something incorrectly, also you seem to have missed the part about the virtualization and still did not provide the definition of your container which could explain why you might not have any virtualization.

Comment: Thanks again H.B, I updated the post and added the conatiner code.

Comment: @leonnoah: If you define an ItemsControl like that all items will be created at once, i have added an example on virtualization but this of course will only help if your grid has enough items that some will be scolled (if you have a scrollviewer around the ItemsControl that should be removed when applying the example).

Comment: Thank you agian H.B!. I had implementd the VirtualizingStackPanel but still, when I wish to display other object's properties, the loading tooks about 1 sec. I know for sure that there some issue with the templating. My big problem is that for each object which I wish to dipsly it's properties has diferent types of data, so every time the controls uses diferent templates. The datacontext of the control is collection of some Viewmodel which wraps the model(property data) and its relevant DataTemple. in this way i implementing the PropertyGrid control. Is my consept wrong?

Comment: @leonnoah: I do not know but i think there is not much you can do except caching, virtualization and minimizing updates.